# Default Spark Listener with arguments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have developed a SparkListener library to log certain actions on a cluster with hundreds of users.

Since, I need the SparkContext on my library (to get some of the objects I need for my logic), I have had to register the Listener manually on the Spark code I want to run.

At this point, I need to register this Listener for all the jobs on cluster, the problem is that I cannot do that using the Spark.extraListeners config because that one requires an argument less constructor.

Thus, my only two options are:

```
 1. Find a way to register a default Listener sending the SparkContext; or
 2. Find a way to "inject": sc.RegisterListener(myClass) upon initialization of all jobs.
```

Any suggestions?